# Correct handling of database errors

Tags: python, django

in views.py have a piece of code:

```
if form.is_valid (): 
     try: 
         obj.family = form.cleaned_data.get ('login') 
         obj.save () 
     except DatabaseError: 
         return HttpResponseRedirect ('/ DBerror /') 
     else: 
         return HttpResponseRedirect ('/ ok_page /')
```

it in case of successful records forwards the user to a specific page. 
in the case of unsuccessful recording code redirects the user to another page.

page with an error message (/ DBerror /) have to do everything myself.

not whether there is a method that will direct the user to the standard page with an error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're using standard Django forms, so you shouldn't be redirecting in case of an error. Instead, you're code should look something like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        # ContactForm was defined in the previous section
        form = ContactForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
            # Process the data in form.cleaned_data
            # ...
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/') # Redirect after POST
    else:
        form = ContactForm() # An unbound form

    return render(request, 'contact.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```

In your template code, each erroneous field will have it's errors available in `{{ field.errors }}` which you can display to the user.

Read more on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/ to see how it all fits together.